# Using the first isomorphism theorem to prove subgroups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

How can I prove that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $HN$ is a subgroup of $G$ using the first isomorphism theorem?

I know how to prove this in general, but my homework problem says that this can be proven using the first isomorphism theorem. Any help in understanding the variation in proof is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Consider the map $\pi: G\to G/N$. Take the image of $H$ and pull it back to $G$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, that comment could be an answer

Comment: @lhf Possibly, but if I were to make it an answer I would prefer to flesh out the details, and I would rather have the OP do those details themselves.